# Gloss, reflection and normal maps not exported in gltf2.0

Tags: texturing, export, normal-map, gltf, reflection

I used the new gltf 2.0 exporter available in blender 2.8 to export a model with three separate elements two of which has gloss, reflection, and normal maps attached to it via principle bsdf one model has gloss value. The problem arises after exporting. The model with custom gloss value works fine but the ones having gloss and normal value through maps appears to have no gloss or normal value. Also I have combined the several separate models into one. I exported the models using. glb extension.

Comment: Are you following this pattern?  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#exported-materials

Comment: No apparently not.. Thanks your link helped a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Could you also tell me what texture to use for metallic roughness map as earlier we had two separate texture maps for each and now we need to use single texture and use different Green and blue channel for values of Metallicness and roughness of materials

Comment: The exporter will combine separate grayscale metallic/roughness images into a single image on export, if you have them hooked up separately.  But you can also combine them in a paint program or such beforehand, to make the export go a little quicker.

Comment: Thanx, I hope this works